# Remove whitespace between bash array elements

Tags: regex, arrays, bash

I'm trying to find a way to not have spaces between the elements of a bash array that I'm using for an AWS CLI command. The filter for the command complains that the filter has to be in the format '--filters name=string1,values=string1,string2'.

The code that I currently have so far:

```
tag_filter=( $(aws ec2 describe-tags --filter "name=value,values=${tags[@]}" | jq '[.Tags[] | {ResourceId}]') )
regex=[[:alpha:]][-][[:xdigit:]]
for x in ${tag_filter[@]}
do
  if [[ $x =~ $regex ]]
  then
    #parameter expansion to remove " from elements
    resource_id+=( "${x//\"}," )
    #$resource_id== "${resource_id_array[@]// /,}" 
  else
    throw error message
  fi
done
echo "${resource_id[@]}"
```

which gives me the output of

```
foo-bar, herp-derp, bash-array,
```

but it needs to be

```
foo-bar,herp-derp,bash-array,
```

for the next filter command to work. All that my searching has come up with is removing spaces in a string, turning a string into an array, or documentation on arrays in general and I haven't seen a similar question anywhere.

EDIT :

I've added anubhava's print statement into my code such that

```
then
  #parameter expansion to remove " from elements
  resource_id_array+=( "${x//\"}," )
  resource_id= $( printf "%s" "${resource_id_array[@]}" )
  resource_id= ${resource_id:1}
  #${resource_id[@]}== "${resource_id[@]// /,}" 
else
```

which now gives me the ouput that I need but give me a ":command not found error" when I run the script after I echo "$resource_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I've ended up doing is this based on anubhava's answer and comments

```
tag_filter=( $(aws ec2 describe-tags --filter "name=value,values=${tags[@]}" | jq '[.Tags[] | {ResourceId}]') )
regex=[[:alpha:]][-][[:xdigit:]]
for x in ${tag_filter[@]}
do
  if [[ $x =~ $regex ]]
  then
    #parameter expansion to remove " from elements
    resource_id+=( "${x//\"}" ) 
  else
    throw error message
  fi
done

resource_id=$( printf "%s" "${resource_id_array[@]}" )
echo "${resource_id[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the way echo works with arrays. Use `printf` like this:

```
printf "%s" "${resource_id[@]}" && echo ""
```

and you should see:

```
foo-bar,herp-derp,bash-array,
```

Comment: That works for getting the output of the array but I need the array itself to be in that format.

Comment: Array just has individual elements. Are you noticing trailing spaces in individual elements also? Try printing it like: `echo "@${resource_id[0]}@"` to verify.